# How to match string in between two words, but only the "closet" of the two words?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am new to regex, and am trying to capture a certain pattern. There are two words (name1 and host), that I want to capture everything in between, the problem is, sometimes "everything" in between might contain 'name1'. And if it does contain 'name1', it includes everything from the previous name1, to the next 'host' word. So I basically have two 'strings' from two different 'name1' being captured.

This is the example I have:

```
name1{want-this-string}host,name1{want-this-string}host,name1{dont-want-this-string},name1{dont-want-this-either}name1{want-this-string}host
```

and this is the regex I'm using right now..

```
(?<=\bname1\b).*?(?=\bhost\b)
```

My expected output is that it matches the 3 `{want-this-string}`, and not the `{dont-want-this}` stuff. so basically:

```
{want-this-string}{want-this-string}{want-this-string}
```

But right now its grabbing the first two `{want this string}` and then this whole section

```
{dont-want-this-string},name1{dont-want-this-either}name1{want-this-string}
```

Comment: You sure this question is related to bash? Bash doesn't support lookarounds afaik.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498213/3832970) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, if this pattern would pass our desired and potential inputs, yet we would similarly start to design an expression based on our cases with a likely left or if necessary right constraints, maybe such as this expression:

```
(^name1|}name1)({.+?})?|(host,name1)({.+?})(host,name1)
```

which this part can be much simplified:

```
(host,name1)({.+?})(host,name1)
```

and we are adding it here just to exemplify the implementation of a right boundary to only capture the first instance of `(host,name1)` value.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmKETY/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pmKETY/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GNU grep, you may use

```
grep -oP '\bname1\{\K[^{}]*(?=}host\b)' file
```

With `pcregrep` (you may install it on MacOS if you are using that OS), you may use it like

```
pcregrep -oM '\bname1\{\K[^{}]*(?=}host\b)' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF46Tu/1)

**Details**

- `\bname1\{`  - whole word `name1` and a `{` after
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the whole match
- `[^{}]*` - 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `(?=}host\b)` - there must be a `}host` as a whole word immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [online grep demo](https://ideone.com/aBadjO):

```
s="name1{want-this-string}host,name1{want-this-string}host,name1{dont-want-this-string},name1{dont-want-this-either}name1{want-this-string}host"
grep -oP '\bname1\{\K[^{}]*(?=}host\b)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
want-this-string
want-this-string
want-this-string
```